# Execute Microsoft Visual Studio project multiple times with different parameters

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I would ask for your help and apologise if the question doesn't make sense.

I have a Microsoft Visual Studio project which I want to execute it multiple times in one go, and every time I will change one parameter.

Please see below the concept:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int size_list = 2;
int my_list[2] = { 5, 6 };

int main()
{
        for (int i = 0; i < size_list; i++)
        {
            cout<<"the number is "<<my_list[i]<<endl;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

So, I would like to replace the loop and instead I will have each element of `my_list` as parameters.

Is there any way to do so?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you are talking about a range based for loop. `for (int val : my_list) {`  [https://ideone.com/zE4fxF](https://ideone.com/zE4fxF)

Comment: If that is not what you want I don't understand the question.

Comment: I want that every time the project ends, and then it starts again with the different parameter. The loop solution runs in the same session.

Comment: Maybe you want to use command line arguments and some other application to run your application in a loop.

Comment: Yes, do you perhaps know how to start with it? Or alternatively is there any way to run multiple VS projects but starting after the one has finished?

Comment: You may want to think about running executables in some type of batch or loop and not worry about running a batch of VS Projects.

Comment: Actually that is very helpful thanks. Just one more please. Is there any way to run the batch file with some parameters? I know how to add the parameters on the batch file but not sure how to pass them on Visual Studio code.

Comment: VSCode or Visual Studio Community these are 2 very different products with a similar name.

Comment: Visual Studio Community 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the parameters in main().

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){std::cout<< argv[1];}
```

And use script like

```
for ($i=0;$i -lt 5; $i++) 
{
#your CPP project and parameters array
   Start-Process test.exe  $arr[0] 
   Wait-Process test
}
```